# Django Template nests script automatically

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.x

AOS and Chart.js files are getting overlapped. I am using django 3.0.5. In the template, I have tried using 1 script block and 2 script blocks, but it still keeps giving the same error. The scripts in the code are in different tags but the response sent by the local server nests the scripts. I've been trying to incorporate aos for the graphs (canvas) in the following project: https://github.com/ruppysuppy/The-WeatherMan-Project

**base.html script part**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% block script %} {% endblock script %} 
{% block script_2 %} {% endblock script_2 %}
```

**weatherdetail.html script part**

```
{% block script %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // TEMPERATURE GRAPH
    var chart_temperature = document.getElementById('tempChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(chart_temperature, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: {{days | safe}},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Maximum Temperature',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)',
                data: {{temp_high | safe}}
            }, {
                label: 'Minimum Temperature',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 150,0,0.9)',
                data: {{temp_low | safe}}
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 50,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    // PRECIPITATION GRAPH
    var chart_precipitation = document.getElementById('precipChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(chart_precipitation, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: {{days | safe}},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Precipitation',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(100, 100, 255)',
                data: {{precipitation | safe}}
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 200,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 40
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    // HUMIDITY GRAPH
    var chart_humidity = document.getElementById('humidChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(chart_humidity, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: {{days | safe}},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Humidity',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.9)',
                data: {{humidity | safe}}
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 100,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 20
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
{% endblock script %}

{% block script_2 %} 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
{% endblock script_2 %}
```

**Result in the website script part**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
    AOS.init();
    </script>
    // TEMPERATURE GRAPH
    var chart_temperature = document.getElementById('tempChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(chart_temperature, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: ['27/04', '26/04', '25/04', '24/04'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Maximum Temperature',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)',
                data: [24.34, 32.64, 34.22, 32.63]
            }, {
                label: 'Minimum Temperature',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 150,0,0.9)',
                data: [23.54, 24.34, 23.16, 22.75]
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 50,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    // PRECIPITATION GRAPH
    var chart_precipitation = document.getElementById('precipChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(chart_precipitation, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: ['27/04', '26/04', '25/04', '24/04'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Precipitation',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(100, 100, 255)',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0]
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 200,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 40
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    // HUMIDITY GRAPH
    var chart_humidity = document.getElementById('humidChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(chart_humidity, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: ['27/04', '26/04', '25/04', '24/04'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Humidity',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.9)',
                data: [87.0, 81.58333333333333, 82.58333333333333, 85.83333333333333]
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 100,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 20
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This too yields the same problem:
**weatherdetail.html script part (using 1 script block)**

```
{% block script %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // TEMPERATURE GRAPH
    var chart_temperature = document.getElementById('tempChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(chart_temperature, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: {{days | safe}},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Maximum Temperature',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)',
                data: {{temp_high | safe}}
            }, {
                label: 'Minimum Temperature',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 150,0,0.9)',
                data: {{temp_low | safe}}
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 50,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    // PRECIPITATION GRAPH
    var chart_precipitation = document.getElementById('precipChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(chart_precipitation, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: {{days | safe}},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Precipitation',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(100, 100, 255)',
                data: {{precipitation | safe}}
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 200,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 40
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    // HUMIDITY GRAPH
    var chart_humidity = document.getElementById('humidChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(chart_humidity, {
        type: 'line',

        data: {
            labels: {{days | safe}},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Humidity',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.9)',
                data: {{humidity | safe}}
            }]
        },

        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 100,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 20
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
{% endblock script %}
```

Comment: Is the result posted grabbed from your browser or is it the __textual__ response body (ie getting it using curl or wget etc) ? It looks like some not correctly closed `script` tag or such but I can't spot such a thing in your code...

Comment: Its from the browser. I too thought that I hadn't closed some script tag, so double checked it, but didn't find it. Btw for reference, the link to the project is here: https://github.com/ruppysuppy/The-WeatherMan-Project I've been trying to incorporate aos in it.

Comment: You should check the literal response body content (using curl or wget or python-requests) to find out if it shows the same issue - it really looks like it's your browser tripping on some malformed HTML or whatever.

Comment: Also: did the issue appeared when you added aos ? Does it persist if you comment out the aos part ?

Comment: Yeah, it appeared when I added aos. Strangely, after restarting my pc (I was going to give python requests and commenting it out a shot), it rectified itself. I didn't even touch the code. Can malformed HTML cause such problems or was some weird code was present in the RAM or cache?

Comment: possibly in your browser's cache??? It's a pity you didn't follow my advice to fetch this page with curl or wget, as this would have made clear whether the issue was with your browser or with django itself - but honestly I fall to see how django templates could yield such results, while it's a very common behavior for browsers dealing with malformed markup or faulty JS.

Comment: Ok. But thanks for the help :)